Weights for representations of the Borel subgroup
Let $L=\mathfrak{sl}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ be the special linear Lie algebra with basis $e,f,h$; and $P$ its Borel sub algebra.
I am trying to understand first the irreducible representations of $P$, and then how to compute what are the singular and regular weights.
First, $P$ is generated by $f,h$ then it is a two-dimensional Lie algebra, satisfying $[h,e] = 2e$, and $[h,h] = [e,e] = 0$, it follows that any representation $\rho: P \to \mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}$, should satisfy $\rho(e) = 0$, hence it is defined by its value on $h$. From here, we should conclude that we have as many representations of $P$ as complex numbers. Restricting to irreducible representations,   from the integrality of the weights, this would imply that we have an irreducible representation for each integer number?
Then, the Cartan-Killing form $\kappa$, is given by $\kappa{e,e} = \kappa(h,h) = 0$, and $\kappa(h,e) = 4$, I am a little lost on how can I concretely associate the weights of each irreducible representation to an element of $<h>$ so that I can compute the Cartan-Killing form to have the singular and regular weights.
Am I in the wrong direction here?

You seem to be assuming that the representations are 1-dimensional and indeed there are as many of those as there are elements of $\mathbb{C}$. These are all irreducible automatically simply by being 1-dimensional. Conversely, any irreducible representation of a solvable Lie algebra has dimension 1.
